# Incorrectly clustered instances in Weka

Tags: cluster-analysis, weka, data-mining

I use `Weka tool` for data mining purpose of mine. When I feed the data set and cluster it using the `SimpleKMeans` algorithm it displays following statement.

```
Incorrectly clustered instances :   857.0    69.7883 %
```

Is it ok to proceed with that percentage ? If not please let me know how to reduce that percentage.

Answer (score 1):

If you have labels, then use them, and do not use clustering at all.

Clustering is meant for data where you do not have labels.

How do you plan to proceed?

Comment: Hi. My target is to cluster people according to the product names. I want to cluster and after that use association rules to suggest similar products. I do not have labels.

Comment: How does clustering help there? Just do Apriori without clustering before.

Comment: Clustering would accurately find out that this consumer would purchase let us say Apple Juice. So once this is prompted and he accepts. Then using apriori algo all the related and simillar products will be suggested.

Comment: That doesn't sound like clustering to me. Apriori can do that.

Comment: Apriori would show the assoications only noh .. In my case i want to be more accurate so I use clustering. Back to the problem is it worth taking the clusters if those have that 69.7 percentage or more ?

Comment: There is no such thing as accuracy of clusters. I think you are totally mixing up things. Apriori will work.

Comment: To be more precise: if your data is in transaction format as used by apriori, then apriori will yield the *optimal* prediction given enough time and memory (this should be easy to prove). Splitting your data using clustering before running apriori then cannot improve over using apriori on all of the data. Things change once apriori cannot use all of the available data.